# Can not use another Class in discord.py bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How can I use the class which does was created without async programming into the discord.py bot?
As there are some methods with while loops and time.sleep, it does not work properly when I initialize the class into the bot.

I also tried to change specific methods to async, but code still does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Right now, the only thing we can possibly say in response to "it does not work properly when I use this code" is "maybe there is something wrong with the code", because you have neither shown us any of the code; nor explained exactly what is supposed to happen, what happens instead and how that is different.

Answer (score -1):

Discord.py is an asynchronous library, you can't do a lot about it. When you want to work with discord.py you have to rewrite your code to work async.
But there is a high chance you could rewrite the other functions to work asynchronous.

As an example, asyncio.sleep() is the async alternative to time.sleep(), etc.

But to help you with your specific code, you have include it in your question.

Maybe this could help too.
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/discussions/8227